# in VS, how do I navigate backwards in code by file?

Tags: visual-studio

In VS, I'm constantly using control+minus and control+plus to go forwards and backwards in my code. However, many times I want to get back to the spot I was that *is not* in the same file.

For instance,

- write code in file A at position A1 and then jump down to position A2 and write more code.
- navigate to file B (usually control-click on an identifier), and write code at positions B1 and B2.

--> What I'd like is a modified control-minus that is knows I'm not interested in jumping to previous points in the same file, and jumps me back to A2.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from just pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> several times, maybe another option for you is to use bookmarks:

<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> <kbd>Ctr-K</kbd> to create/delete a bookmark

<kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> to cycle to the next bookmark in the list

of course you don't want to be leaving bookmarks everywhere otherwise this becomes tedious to use...

Comment: the problem with several Ctrl--'s isn't the physical exertion on my finger but the subroutine my already overly busy brain has to execute to watch for the moment when file changes.. couple that with possible UI lag in VS2010 and a lifetime of playing arcade shooters and its downright annoying at times :)